# How to use if construction for controller vars in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Prompt, as if working in angularjs. I try to do so:

```
var goods = angular.module ('goods', []);
goods.controller('Cart', function ($scope) {
  $scope.goodsCount = 1,
});
```

In html I have tried many things:

```
<div ng-app="goods" ng-controller="Cart">
  <span ng-if="goodsCount> 1"> 1 </span>
<div>
```

And it did not work

```
<div ng-app="goods" ng-controller="Cart">
  <span> {{goodsCount > 1 ? goodsCount: 'null'}} </ span>
<div>
```

And it is also

So how does it work?

Comment: is `$ scope` just a typo in your example code here? Or is that your actual code?

Comment: You have your controller declared in code as `Cart`, but in your HTML your reference `ng-controller="Basket"`

Comment: it's a typo. I corrected

Comment: Check your console, you probably have errors..

Comment: @tymeJV it is also a typo. Console empty

Comment: What's the actual question here?

Comment: You have a comma at the end of this line `$scope.goodsCount = 1,`. Do you want me to continue. I'm sure i can find some more...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your controller is called Cart and you're putting ng-controller="Basket" on the scope. Also, you are probably wanting to use ng-show.

Try:

```
<div ng-app="goods" ng-controller="Cart">
   <span ng-show="goodsCount > 1"> {{ goodsCount }} </ span>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So there's a few issues that were corrected by other comments. Once those are actually fixed in your code it will work. Double check your working code for typos as well. Here is an example of this working with your code that you have supplied without typos.

```
plunker
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/t4yAKgTdYzt18YUZmX5M?p=preview

In the script file you can change the value to see the different things appear or change.

Oh and yes forgot to mention, the comma after your $scope.goodsCount was breaking it. That is also fixed in the plunker